# Android: Disable AlertDialogBuilder's OK button on certain conditions

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

So I have a menu that pops up when a button is clicked. In that menu, user can enter "Assignment Name" which can be a String, and "Grade" and "Max Points Available" which will be numbers.
Now I want to make sure that User doesn't enter nothing or `null`in any of those EditText fields. So is there a way to disable the `OK` button until valid input is entered. Below is a picture of what the pop-up looks like.

[image]

Below is my code in MainActivity

```
Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.add_individual_name, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText assignmentName = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.enteredIndividualName);
            final EditText gradeReceived = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.enteredUserGrade);
            final EditText maxPoints = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.enteredMaxPoints);
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String name = assignmentName.getText().toString();
                            String grade = gradeReceived.getText().toString();
                            String totalPossible = maxPoints.getText().toString();
                            checkIfNameAlreadyExists(name);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }});
```

Also, I want to disable the "OK" button if the "Assignment Name" already exists in my Database. I have a function that checks if item exits in DB.

Let me know if you want to see the code for XML of `AlertDialog` or anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `TextWatcher` for your `EditText`. And in afterTextChanged, simply check the condition for enable/disable OK button

```
// Your alert dialog config
...
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();

// disable the button as default start
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

// add TextWatcher for EditText
editTextAssignmentName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (s.length() >= 1) { // add your condition here, in your case it is checkIfNameAlreadyExists
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But where exactly do I put that block of code? If I put it before line `alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)` then the "OK" button just disappear and if I put it after that line, then it has no effect.

Comment: try put the block of code like my answer (after final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();)

Comment: That worked perfectly as I expected. Thank you very much!